# error: unable to resolve reference refs/heads/branch/A: Not a directory

Tags: git

I got this error when doing a `git push --all`:

```
error: unable to resolve reference refs/heads/branch/A: Not a directory
remote: error: Cannot lock the ref 'refs/heads/branch/A'.
```

Any idea how to get around this?

Comment: How was the remote repo initialized?

Comment: Do you have another branch named just `refs/heads/branch`?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try cleaning up your repository?

```
$ git gc --prune=now
$ git remote prune origin
```

I'm not entirely sure if this will fix it but can you once try it?